# Memory Leak when refresh Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, activity-finish

I have a problem !

For refresh activity I use this code :

```
Intent i=getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

The problem is that the memory increasing, when run many times this opertion, and the app crash for OutOfMemory.

How i can resolve this ? Any solutions?

Please help me

[This is Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOGpf.png)

Comment: Post the exact exception from logcat as well.

Comment: I've posting the Logcat

Comment: Are you using any jpeg image anywhere or inside onCreateView in the MapFragment

Answer (score 1):

Maybe`Intent` has some type of reference to the `Activity` why don't you try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it's because your code is not optimized to avoid memory leak. Here's some tips to avoid it:

> Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself)
>
> Try using the context-application instead of a context-activity
>
> Avoid non-static inner classes in an activity if you don't control
>   their life cycle, use a static inner class and make a weak reference
>   to the activity inside. The solution to this issue is to use a static
>   inner class with a WeakReference to the outer class, as done in
>   ViewRoot and its inner class for instance
>   A garbage collector is not an insurance against memory leaks

Read this article for more detail: [Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Answer (score 0):

the new answer, but maybe someone will read this...
Kill all references that are active, when recreating activity. Maybe some object that is still active, and has reference to it, after you call that `finish()` method. Context also is one of the most leak-able classes, use it wisely.

I personally call recreate on activity and then override it...

```
    override fun recreate() {
    finish()
    viewMvc.cancelTimer()
    viewMvc.unregisterListener(this)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

viewMvc here is my view separated from the activity

Happy coding